# Embedded Geofence and standalone geofence

Tags: geoserver-geofence

I am using 2.11.0 version of both Geofence embedded and Geofence standalone applications running in different ports. In embedded, for a user, I am able to provide both read and write access for a workspace.

[image]

[image]

[image]

But, in geofence standalone application, I am not able to give write access for that particular workspace.If admin is enabled for that user, then that user is provided with full admin access(all workspaces are visible like admin user)

[image]

[image]

1. Is it possible to provide both read and write access for a particular workspace using standalone geofence (like embedded geofence) ?